# Delete all records older than 2 days SpringData / custom query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to delete all records from my database that are older than 2 days but I keep getting this not-so-useful error so I don't know what to do:

```
Some problem occured: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

My code looks like this:

In one class I'm calling testService's deleteOldRecords method:

```
// Delete records older than two days (takes current time and then removes 2 days from today's date (172 800 000 ms = 2 days)
                testService.deleteOldRecords((ZonedDateTime.now().toInstant().toEpochMilli())-172_800_000);
```

This is the implementation of that method:

```
@Override
public void deleteOldRecords(long timestamp) {
    testDao.deleteOldRecordsCRUD(timestamp);        
}
```

Now I'm trying to call deleteOldRecordsCRUD which is a custom query. Here's the method:

```
    @Repository
public interface TestItemDAO extends CrudRepository<TestItem, Long> {
    //This will delete records older then two days!
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM TEST_TABLE tt WHERE tt.timestamp <= :timestamp", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteOldRecordsCRUD(@Param("timestamp") long timestamp);
}
```

I have table created, with some records in it but this is not working, that is, records still exist in DB after testDao.deleteOldRecordsCRUD(timestamp); is called. (Because of the error that appears on that line, but due to poor log, I don't know what went wrong.)

I checked SpringDocumentation and it seems that I got everything right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the @Transactional annotation from Spring package
like `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`
At method level.